# Perl Irssi scripting: rename invalid DCC file

Tags: perl, scripting, irssi

I'm on Windows, using Irssi client irssi-win32-0.8.12.exe.

I'm having problems receiving a file with invalid name:

```
..nameo_\u2605_name.. (err: DCC can't create file)
```

How can I strip this invalid part "\u2605" from filename, using script?

[This page](http://www.irssi.org/documentation/perl) doesn't help

I think this [part of the Irssi source](https://github.com/zewt/irssi/blob/master/src/irc/dcc/dcc-get.c) has something to do with it. Starting at line 195

```
/* if some plugin wants to change the file name/path here.. */
signal_emit("dcc get receive", 1, dcc);
```

Comment: `\u2605` is Unicode U+2605, a Black Star - ★. You can't just remove characters in a Unicode file name as you would risk filename clashes. You need to support Unicode throughout your program.

Comment: well i will resolve filename clashes somehow. True purpose is to be able change filename

Comment: well i will resolve filename clashes somehow. 
True purpose is to be able change filename AT GET TIME, not after dowload. 
It does't matter - either have ascii only filename, or change all spaces to underscores.

Answer (score 0):

I sure hope Irssi on Windows accepts scripts written in Perl. If this is the case, here's the solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our $VERSION = "1.0";
our %IRSSI = ();

# interception made by registering signal as first + Irssi::signal_continue()
sub event_ctcp_dccsend {
    my ($server, $args, $nick, $addr, $target) = @_;

    # split incomming send request args into filename (either before first space or
    #  quoted), and the rest (IP, port, +optionally filesize)
    my ($filename, $rest) = $args =~ /((?:".*")|\S*)\s+(.*)/;

    # remember file name for informing sake
    my $oldname = $filename;
    # replace backslashes with "BSL" (change to anything you wish)
    if ($filename =~ s/\\/BSL/g) {
        # some info for user
        Irssi::print('DCC SEND request from '.$nick.': renamed bad filename '.$oldname.' to '.$filename);
        $args = $filename." ".$rest;
        # propagate signal; Irssi will proceed the request with altered arguments ($args) 
        Irssi::signal_continue($server, $args, $nick, $addr, $target);  
    }
}

# register signal of incoming ctcp 'DCC SEND', before anything else
Irssi::signal_add_first('ctcp msg dcc send', 'event_ctcp_dccsend');
```

The script intercepts "DCC SEND" ctcp messages and **replaces** all backslashes in the filename into "BSL" string, then forwards altered arguments of message to any other scripts and Irssi.
If you want to **remove** all "\uXXXX" instead, use `s/\\u\w{4}//g` in place of `s/\\/BSL/g`

I hope it helps!